# listbox datasource update ms access winform

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, listbox, datasource

i create a winform application with a listbox datasource that come from ms access database. the problem is when i click the Update button the listbox is not getting update. example i change the "ITEM1" to ITEM2", its just not working but the database do because i execute a command that will update the database. i need to reload(re-open) my application then on that time i will see my modification. how do i update the listbox? i've read something about this problem before but i dont understand about it clearly..i wish someone could help me out..

```
    private BindingList<PRODUCTLIST> _productlist;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class PRODUCTLIST
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string ITEM { get; set; }
        public string ITEM_DESC { get; set; }
    }

    private static OleDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        OleDbConnection mdbConn = new OleDbConnection();
        try
        {
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=shop.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxx;";
            mdbConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            mdbConn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        return mdbConn;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make ID textbox un editable
        textBoxID.Enabled = false;

        _productlist = new BindingList<PRODUCTLIST>();
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY ITEM";
        OleDbDataAdapter myCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, GetConnection());
        DataSet dtSet = new DataSet();
        myCmd.Fill(dtSet, "Item");
        DataTable dTable = dtSet.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            _productlist.Add(new PRODUCTLIST() { ID = dtRow["ID"].ToString(), ITEM = dtRow["ITEM"].ToString(), ITEM_DESC = dtRow["ITEM_DESC"].ToString() });
        }
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ITEM";
        listBox1.DataSource = _productlist;
        //listBox1.DataBindings = _productlist;
        listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

        // set the textbox binding and DataSourceUpdateMode to Never because i have other button to add the new item
        textBoxID.DataBindings.Add("Text", _productlist, "ID", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
        textBoxITEM.DataBindings.Add("Text", _productlist, "ITEM", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
        textBoxITEMDESC.DataBindings.Add("Text", _productlist, "ITEM_DESC", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
    }

    private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update data on database
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Item SET ITEM = @ITEM, ITEM_DESC = @ITEM_DESC WHERE ID = @ID", GetConnection());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM", textBoxITEM.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM_DESC", textBoxITEMDESC.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(textBoxID.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // make the listbox datasource update
        //listBox1.Refresh();
        //listBox1.DataSource = null;
        //listBox1.DataSource = _productlist;

        //_productlist = new BindingList<PRODUCTLIST>();
        //string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY ITEM";
        //OleDbDataAdapter myCmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, GetConnection());
        //DataSet dtSet = new DataSet();
        //myCmd.Fill(dtSet, "Item");
        //DataTable dTable = dtSet.Tables[0];
        //foreach (DataRow dtRow in dTable.Rows)
        //{
        //    _productlist.Add(new PRODUCTLIST() { ID = dtRow["ID"].ToString(), ITEM = dtRow["ITEM"].ToString(), ITEM_DESC = dtRow["ITEM_DESC"].ToString() });
        //}
        //listBox1.DisplayMember = "ITEM";
        //listBox1.DataSource = _productlist;
        ////listBox1.DataBindings = _productlist;
        //listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it you need to clear and repopulate your list box.

You should extract that code as a method from the FormLoad event handler and call it after you run the update query.

It's hard to tell which way you want to go. Based on what you are asking.
What you should be doing is making your products data table a private property. Creating and open it up and bind to the list box.

Then your update function should be changing the datatable. Then you'd see the changes in your list box. The thing to appreciate though is until you flush the changes (ApplyChanges method) you have made to the datatable back to the database server all you've done is change a local copy of the data.
That can be good and bad. Depends on what you want to do with multiple users updating products at the same time.

So you've got datatable with a local copy and shown it.
Then you've updated the table you copied, and now your copy is out of step.
Exactly the same problem you would have, if you ran up another copy of your app and changed one of the records you'd already shown in the first one.

Comment: did you mean i need to create something like this?
private void fill()
{
//connect to database and do select query..
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
fill();
}

private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//my update query are same as question
fill();
}

???

Comment: Either you repopulate the listbox after the query, or you get rid of the query and update the data table instead.